# Get the filename part from a given URL

Tags: php, regex

I have a URL like below:

```
http://abc.def.com/gh-tqa/name-of-the-file/ZW607CCF.html
```

Now I want to get the string of `ZW607CCF` without `.html`.

How can I achieve this using PHP?

Comment: Have you tried anything?  Considering that you included the `regex` tag, is there some regular expression that you have tried?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need a regex here. Just use [`pathinfo()`](http://php.net/pathinfo):

```
$url = 'http://abc.def.com/gh-tqa/name-of-the-file/ZW607CCF.html';
$filename = pathinfo($url, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
```

Comment: @amal murali nice one. We have a lack of php function details. That's why our solutions always tends to `regex`

Comment: Good job. how can I get "name-of-the-file" without "-" also and put it into a new value? Just like "name of the file"

Comment: @anubhava: Something as simple as this does not require a regex. "*Don't bring a gun to a knife fight.*" comes to mind :D

Comment: @SabujHassan: PHP has functions for almost *everything*. You just have to dig them up from the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/funcref.php). :)

Comment: @AmalMurali: Very true, since I have never written any PHP code in my job so regex usually comes naturally if question is tagged so.

Comment: Thanks @AmalMurali It will help, though I don't do too much coding with PHP.

Comment: I have a variable: $Name = "name of the file" . Now I download a file and store in it with that name and its extension. I used cURL. $fp = fopen ('download/$Name.zip' , 'w+'); $ch = curl_init($downurl);//Here is the file we are downloading But this didn't work. It saved a file named $Name.zip I am learning php. Please help me. Thanks!

Comment: @user3468831: Sounds like another problem. Please [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Cheers!

Comment: `Pathinfo()` returns the "directory name" as filename if your url is a "section front page" (like `http://www.example.com/foo/`). Example: `print_r(pathinfo('http://www.example.com/foo/'));` outputs `[ 'dirname' => http://www.example.com, 'basename' => foo, 'filename' => foo ]`

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of ways in PHP, try `preg_replace()`, for example:

```
$url = 'http://abc.def.com/gh-tqa/name-of-the-file/ZW607CCF.html';
$value = preg_replace("|.*/([^.]+)\.html|", "$1", $url);
```

Comment: This is what I want. Btw, how can I get "name-of-the-file" without "-" also and put it into a new value? Just like "name of the file"

Comment: `preg_match('|.*/([^/]+)/([^.]+)\.html|', $url, $m);` after that `$m[1]` will hold your value. From there replace hyphens using `str_replace()`

Comment: I have a variable: $Name = "name of the file" . Now I download a file and store in it with that name and its extension.

I used cURL.

$fp = fopen ('download/$Name.zip' , 'w+');
$ch = curl_init($downurl);//Here is the file we are downloading

But this didn't work. It saved a file named $Name.zip
I am learning php. Please help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

this is how you do:

```
$temp = explode('.', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

$string = $temp[0];
```

with PHP 5.4+ you can also do:

```
$string = explode('.', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])[0];
```